# Minimizing sum of absolute values of differences

Tags: algorithm

[An SPOJ question](http://www.spoj.com/problems/DCOWS/):

Given two arrays, `A` and `B`, of positive numbers between `1` and `1,000,000`. I have to pair each integer `a` in `A` with an integer `b` in `B` such that the sum of absolute values of differences is minimized. `A` and `B` can contain a maximum of 5000 integers each.

**For example:**

Let `A=[10, 15, 13]` and `B=[14,13, 12]`, then the best pairing is `(10, 12)`, `(15, 14)` and `(13, 13)` because `|10-12|+|15-14|+|13-13|=3`, which is the least we can achieve. Thus, the minimum sum achieved is `3`.

I believe it is a dynamic programming question.

**Edit:**

The arrays may be of different sizes but can contain a maximum of 5000 elements each.

**My code:**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

static int DP[5002][5002], N, M, tmp;
vector<int> B, C;

int main()
{
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &M); memset(DP, -1, sizeof DP);
    B.push_back(0); C.push_back(0); DP[0][0]=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=N; ++i){scanf("%d", &tmp); B.push_back(tmp);} \\inputting numbers.
    for(int i=1; i<=M; ++i){scanf("%d", &tmp); C.push_back(tmp);}
    sort(B.begin(), B.end()); sort(C.begin(), C.end());         \\Sorting the two arrays.

    if(C.size()<=B.size()){                         \\Deciding whether two swap the order of arrays.
        for(int i=1; i<=N; ++i){
            for(int j=1; j<=M; ++j){
                if(j>i)break;
                if(j==1)DP[i][j]=abs(C[j]-B[i]);
                else{
                    tmp=DP[i-1][j-1]+abs(C[j]-B[i]);
                    DP[i][j]=(DP[i-1][j]!=-1)? min(tmp, DP[i-1][j]): tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", DP[N][M]);    \\Outputting the final result.
    }
    else{
        for(int i=1; i<=M; ++i){
            for(int j=1; j<=N; ++j){
                if(j>i) break;
                if(j==1)DP[i][j]=abs(C[i]-B[j]);
                else{
                    tmp=DP[i-1][j-1]+abs(C[i]-B[j]);
                    DP[i][j]=(DP[i-1][j]!=-1)? min(tmp, DP[i-1][j]): tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", DP[M][N]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the solution to just sort both arrays and pair them off, iterating A forward and B reverse? Or at least that would be the base case I'd try to make improvements off of, if not

Comment: @Patashu No, both arrays in the same direction.

Comment: @Kolink Oops, yeah, you're right

Comment: If both arrays are of the same size, and every number needs to be used exactly once, you only need to sort and pair them indeed. I suspect the intended problem is a bit harder though and OP forgot to mention something, or it's a *"gotcha"* question by the interviewer.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BlSXH.png Mathematically speaking what you have is two _vectors_ and the "sum of absolute differences" is the distance in Taxicab Geometry. @NielsKeurentjes is right if the conditions are indeed as you mentioned. Are you sure you're not forgetting anything?

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes do you know where I can find a mathematical proof of that result ? It seems easy but I somehow can't figure out a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Niels's comment elucidates that, if the arrays are of the same size, then you should sort them and pair the values. We can build on that to construct the general case:

I'll assume the length of the first array `arr1` is smaller than or equal to the length of the second `arr2`. If it isn't, just swap them. First, sort both arrays, and let `dp[A][B]` be the smallest difference when you consider only the subarrays `arr1[A...]` and `arr2[B...]` (that is, `arr1` from *`A`* forward and `arr2` from *`B`* to the end). You have two choices:

- Pair *`A`* and *`B`*. In this case you'd get a total difference of `|arr1[A]-arr2[B]| + dp[A+1][B+1]`.
- Don't use *`B`*. Note that in this case you'll never consider *`B`* again (because if you pair *`A`* and *`B`* to different elements, then you could swap both pairs and the sum would go down). So you can simply ignore *`B`* and your answer will be `dp[A][B+1]`.

Base cases should be fairly obvious:

- `dp[length of arr1][length of arr2] = 0`
- `dp[A][length of arr2] = infinity` (it's impossible to pair the remaining elements of `arr1`).

Comment: Please see the edit 2 and help me out. I have done as you said. But getting wrong answer on SPOJ judge.

Comment: I don't think the j==1 condition is correct. Test cases with a one-element C array, such as (1, 2, 3, 4)  and (1).

Comment: @ffao i think `dp[length of arr1][B] = infinity` should also be there . Correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: Not necessarily, as some elements in array B can be unmatched in the end. dp[length of arr1][B] should be 0.